# What is the difference between .get() and get_object_or_404() in Django post() definition?

Tags: django-views

I have this code in a class based view:

```
def post(self, request,pk,slug, **kwargs):
        self.page = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Which gives the template access to the attributes of the object from Post model with the given pk.

However, when I do this:

```
def post(self, request,pk,slug, **kwargs):
        self.page = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
```

The template does not recognize the page variable. Thanks for any explanations.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `get` or `get_object_or_404`. The rest of the view needs to eventually pass it to the template, for example by overriding the `get_context_data`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I have overridden get_context_data. The problem was post() was being called before it, so I had to add the context directly into post(). Not sure how you can say it has nothing to do with get or get_object_or_404 because one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: `self.page = ...` does not changes anything to the context. You in *both* cases access it through `{{ view.page }}` however, since the view is implictly passed. But if you only change `self.page = Post.objects.get(..)` to `self.page = get_object_or_404(...)` and vice versa, this will not have an impact on the object being passed to the template or not.

Comment: I still don't understand. When I use this for an invalid form: `return render(request, 'blog/comment.html', {'form': form, 'page': self.page})` I can access page.attribtute on the template using .get(), but not get_object_or_404.